# Determine when using the VC90 compiler in VS2010 instead of VS2008?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, macros, visual-c++-2008, visual-c++-2010

Is there a (Microsoft-specific) CPP macro to determine when I'm using the VC9 compiler in Visual Studio 2010 as opposed to Visual Studio 2008?  `_MSC_VER` returns the *compiler* version, so with VS2010 multi-targeting feature, I'll get the same result as with VS2008.

The reason for wanting to know the difference is that I created a new VS2010 project which contains code removed from a larger project.  I just left the VS2008 stuff "as is" since we're moving away from VS2008 "soon" anyway and I didn't want to go through the hassle of creating a **vcproj** file along with the new **vcxproj**.

For now, I've just defined my own macro to indicate whether the code is compiled into its own DLL or not; it works just fine, but it would be nice if there were something slightly more elegant.

Comment: A quick test shows that if you change the platform toolset to **v90**, `_MSC_VER` is `1500` which is correct; are you not seeing the same results?

Comment: The compiler itself obviously can't know the difference-  it's the same compiler - so you'd need some information passed from the outside to VC9 anyway. Hence, your /D solution is as elegant as any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is no solution, a custom macro works even if it isn't quite as elegant as I would like.

Answer (score 1):

> `_MSC_VER` returns the compiler version

It sounds like that's what you really do want (or am I misunderstanding?).

If the compiler from VS2008 (which confusingly is also known as VC9 or cl.exe 15.0) is being used, then `_MSC_VER` will return a value that's greater than or equal to 1500.  If the compiler from VS2010 is used (also known as VC10 or cl.exe 16.0), then `_MSV_VER` will evaluate to 1600.

Comment: @Dan - I see.  Can you give an bit more detail on why you want to know which IDE is kicking off the build?  I'm curious about understanding the motivation.